# What's the name of the track that plays in One Piece Episode 630 from 13:30 - 14:00?

Tags: one-piece, music

The soundtrack that plays when Fujitora makes his first appearance.
Episode 630 13:30-14:00 
I have heard the soundtrack many times before. This soundtrack relates to a swordsman, that's how I feel.

Thanks

Comment: WHAT?!! NO ONE knows it???

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The name of the OST is "Greeting Swordsman" and is from [One Piece Movie 7: The Giant Mechanical Soldier of Karakuri Castle](http://myanimelist.net/anime/465/One_Piece:_Karakurijou_no_Mecha_Kyohei)

[Here](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=ruBm9M-2vds) is the link to the OST and [here](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=pJwz7cY8Sk8) is the extended version.